# Date.newInstance function not throwing error when we enter invalid date

Tags: apex, date

I am using `Date.newInstance` for entering the date through the apex.

For example : `System.debug('Test1'+Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf('2021'), Integer.valueOf('2'), Integer.valueOf('31')));`

The above date is Feb 31, which is invalid but while debugging I get the 3rd of march as there are 28 days in Feb and we entered 31 which is 3 days from 28th Feb and hence we get 3rd march. Do we have something where we can check if the date provided by the user is valid or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a [valueOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_valueOf) method of `Date` class. The specified string should use the standard date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in the local time zone. If the date is not valid, the exception is thrown. Catch it and handle it accordingly.

```
String dateToCheck = '2021-02-31';
try {
   Date d = Date.valueOf(dateToCheck);
} catch(TypeException ex) {
   // handle it
}
```